# Drawing an Object when Class is called

Tags: java, oop, class, object

I'm new to object oriented programming. I'm playing around with creating objects. I have class Cat, which I want to draw a circle (representing a cat) when I call it from another program called CatDemo. It's not working, and I would like to know if there is any way to draw an object when you make it.

Here's my Cat code:

```
public class Cat {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        StdDraw.circle(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
    }
}
```

And here I am trying to make a new Cat.

```
public class CatDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create two different 
        // Cat objects
        Cat cat1 = new Cat();
        Cat cat2 = new Cat(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: If you're expecting that `Cat#main` will be executed when you create a new `Cat`, then you're totally wrong. This is very basic. Please check a Java book or tutorial.

Comment: @m0skit0 obviously it is not basic to the OP; they asked a question about it.

Comment: But AFAIK this is not a site to teach him/her Java or OOP, but to provide concise answers to specific questions :)

Comment: @m0skit0 gotta agree with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are currently doing is creating a `main` method in your class `Cat`. `void main(String[])` is called the **entry point** of a program; when you run a program, the code will be executed starting in the`main` method. If you want to run code when a `Cat` is constructed, you must create a **constructor** for `Cat`. Here's what you want (I think):

```
public class Cat
{
    // this is the constructor. it is run whenever you make a new Cat object.
    public Cat()
    {
        StdDraw.circle(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
    }
}
public class CatDemo { ... original code is fine ... }
```

Comment: +1 for explaining what `main` and a constructor are in Java instead of just providing code. You might also want to explain what's an instance, and the difference with `static`.

Comment: If the OP doesn't understand the difference between main() and a constructor, then he/she should perhaps read a book on Java. That would be a much better explanation that I can give...

Comment: He obviously doesn't. That's why I didn't bother to answer this (see my comment on OP). IMHO this question is not constructive as per SO standards.

Comment: @m0skit0 Then downvote it.

Comment: Thanks feralin for your help! I am reading a java book and just have questions along the way. I'm open to advice on asking more constructive questions.

Comment: @user2009020 your welcome! I only have a little advice about good questions: try googling a lot first, because, honestly, you can ask either Google or God, but Google is usually faster. And then you don't ask a question that looks like you did no research at all.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a `main` method (executed when you **run** `Cat`):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    StdDraw.circle(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
}
```

use a constructor (executed when a `Cat` is **created**):

```
public Cat(){
    StdDraw.circle(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
}
```